# Explicit Laplace approximation for tail of gaussian distribution

Tags: probability-theory, large-deviation-theory

I'm studying [some lecture notes by S. R. Srinivasa Varadhan](https://math.nyu.edu/faculty/varadhan/LDP/1-2.pdf) about Large Deviations Theory and I have some trouble understanding a simple equation right on page 2 where it says
$$\frac{\sqrt{n}}{2\pi} \int_l^\infty \exp{\left(-\frac{nx^2}{2}\right)}\mathrm dx=\exp{\left(-\frac{n l^2}{2}+o(n) \right)}.$$
The left side of the equation looks to be the same as $1-\Phi(\sqrt{n}x)=\Phi(-\sqrt{n}x)$ where $\Phi$ is the standard normal CDF. But I don't see how to get there: Is this a simple (approximative) calculation or a fact about the normal distribution?

Comment: Indeed, Laplace approximation shows that, when $x\to+\infty$, $$\int_x^\infty e^{-t^2/2}dt=e^{-x^2/2}\int_0^\infty e^{-xt}e^{-t^2/2}dt= e^{-x^2/2}\frac1x\int_0^\infty e^{-t}e^{-t^2/(2x^2)}dt\sim e^{-x^2/2}\frac1x,$$ in the sense that $$xe^{x^2/2}\cdot\int_x^\infty e^{-t^2/2}dt\to1.$$ The expansion in your post is a weak form of this since $\frac1x=e^{o(x^2)}$ and $\frac1{2\pi}=e^{o(x^2)}$ when $x\to+\infty$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I actually didn't know about Laplac approximation at all, but the method seems to be pretty vital in large deviations theory, so I'd better get used to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the left hand side,
\begin{align*}
\frac{\sqrt{n}}{2\pi} \int_l^\infty \exp\left\{-\frac{nx^2}{2}\right\}\,dx
&=\frac{\sqrt{n}}{2\pi} \int_l^\infty \exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x}{1/\sqrt n}\right)^2\right\}\,dx\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{n}}{2\pi}\cdot\sqrt{2\pi}(1/\sqrt n) \int_l^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}(1/\sqrt n)}\exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x}{1/\sqrt n}\right)^2\right\}\,dx\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{2\pi}\int_l^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}(1/\sqrt n)}\exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x}{1/\sqrt n}\right)^2\right\}\,dx\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{2\pi}\int_{l\sqrt n}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}(1/\sqrt n)}\exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2}u^2\right\}\,\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt n}\,du\right)\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{2\pi}\int_{l\sqrt n}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2}u^2\right\}\,du\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\left[1-\Phi\left(\sqrt n l\right)\right]
\end{align*}

Comment: Actually the LHS is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\left[1-\Phi\left(\sqrt n l\right)\right]$, as claimed by the OP, modulo the irrelevant $\sqrt{2\pi}$ missing factor.

Comment: @Did I have been staring at this for a while. I knew something was wrong. Did you happen to spot it?

Comment: @Did Nevermind, found it!